# Why is Django generating a new session_key every time I refresh and hit a route?

Tags: django, session, session-cookies

I don't have SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE set to true, I don't have req.session.modified set to true. And it seems like my browser cookie has a session id that's not changing on refresh. BUT, when I refresh the page and it re-hits the route, poof, I get a new `session_key`. So what could be causing this? I would like to keep the same session key, because I'm using it for user analytics tracking.

[image: browser cookie id]

[image: printing the session id each refresh]

Comment: What's the browser and Django version you are using?

Comment: @ahmed Django: 4.0.3, Chrome 100.0.4896.127